# Can't send anything to Azure IoT hub

Tags: azure, arduino, azure-iot-hub

I am working on a project where I need to send data from an Arduino sensor to Azure IoT hub via MQTT SIMCOM SIM7000E.

The device connects fine however when it comes to sending anything it fails. I think it may be the way I've configured my credentials?

IP: "hub.azure-devices.net"

Client: "Sensor_0001"

Username: "hub.azure-devices.net/Sensor_0001/?api-version=2018-06-30"

Key: "SharedAccessSignature sr=Hub.azure-devices.net%2Fdevices%2FSensor_0001&sig=****"

Topic: "Hub/devices/Sensor_0001/messages/events"

I am very new to this and would appreciate any help or suggestions.

Thanks

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <DFRobot_SIM7000.h>
#include "Adafruit_FONA.h"
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
 
#define serverIP        "EEWHub.azure-devices.net"
#define IOT_CLIENT      "EEW_Sensor_0001"
#define IOT_USERNAME    "EEWHub.azure-devices.net/EEW_Sensor_0001/?api-version=2018-06-30"
#define IOT_KEY         "SharedAccessSignature sr=EEWHub.azure-devices.net%2Fdevices%2FEEW_Sensor_0001&sig=ayW2DcT3YOJGQK6Ch8hEJyNF7MIaT%2BukyfJY03J1Y%2BM%3D&se=1632246687"
#define IOT_TOPIC       "devices/EEW_Sensor_0001/messages/events/"

#define PIN_TX          7
#define PIN_RX          8

SoftwareSerial          mySerial(PIN_RX, PIN_TX);
DFRobot_SIM7000         sim7000;

void simconnect() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  while (!Serial);
  sim7000.begin(mySerial);
  Serial.println("Turn ON SIM7000......");
  if (sim7000.turnON()) {                                      //Turn ON SIM7000
    Serial.println("Turn ON !");
  }
  delay(10000);
  Serial.println("Set baud rate......");
  while (1) {
    if (sim7000.setBaudRate(19200)) {                        //Set SIM7000 baud rate from 115200 to 19200 reduce the baud rate to avoid distortion
      Serial.println("Set baud rate:19200");
      break;
    } else {
      Serial.println("Fail to set baud rate");
      delay(1000);
    }
  }

  Serial.println("Attaching service......");
  while (1) {
    if (sim7000.attachService()) {                          //Open the connection
      Serial.println("Attach service");
      break;
    } else {
      Serial.println("Fail to Attach service");
      delay(1000);
    }
  }
}

void loop() {
  String  sendData;
  Serial.print("Connect to :");
  Serial.println(serverIP);
  if (sim7000.openNetwork(TCP, serverIP, 8883)) {              //Connect to server
    Serial.println("Connected !");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Failed to connect");
    return;
  }
  delay(200);

  Serial.print("Connect to : ");
  Serial.println(IOT_USERNAME);
  if (sim7000.mqttConnect(IOT_CLIENT, IOT_USERNAME, IOT_KEY)) { //MQTT connect request
    Serial.println("Connected !");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Failed to connect");
    return;
  }
  delay(200);

  Serial.println("Input data end with CRLF : ");
  sendData = readSerial(sendData);
  Serial.print("Send data : ");
  Serial.print(sendData);
  Serial.println(" ......");
  if (sim7000.mqttPublish(IOT_TOPIC, sendData)) {              //Send data to topic
    Serial.println("Send OK");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Failed to send");
    return;
  }
  delay(200);

  Serial.println("Close connection......");
  if (sim7000.closeNetwork()) {                                //Close connection
    Serial.println("Close connection !");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Fail to close connection !");
    return;
  }
  delay(2000);
}

String readSerial(String result) {
  int i = 0;
  while (1) {
    while (Serial.available() > 0) {
      char inChar = Serial.read();
      if (inChar == '\n') {
        result += '\0';
        while (Serial.read() >= 0);
        return result;
      }
      if (i == 50) {
        Serial.println("The data is too long");
        result += '\0';
        while (Serial.read() >= 0);
        return result;
      }
      if (inChar != '\r') {
        result += inChar;
        i++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It fails how? What error do you get? Where is the code?

Comment: As it connects it says "connected!" but when it sends anything it says "Failed to send". I have uploaded the code however I am using a library that came with the Sim7000e. It gets up to AT+CIPSEND and I assume that is where it stops.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your topic is not correct. Try the following:

```
devices/Sensor_0001/messages/events/
```

Have a look at this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support) for more details.

The following screen snippet shows the MQTTBox client example:

[image]

**Update:**

I have tested connectivity from your example and the following screen shows a result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have changed the topic to that and it still doesn't send... Maybe its a bad library that came with the modem? Not too sure

Comment: if the topic is not correct, the device is disconnected from the Azure IoT Hub. I do recommend to use MQTTBox client tool for test purposes.